# Codeigniter: How to track whether the new customer sign up is through the existing customer's reference?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a CRM, in which there is a option for **refering a friend**.

When any existing customer refer the product to his/her friend, then that *referred friend* and *the customer too* get some discount on the purchase.

While inserting the friend's information (`friendName`, `friendContact`, `friendEmail`) I am fetching the customer's `id` (`referedByCustomerId`) in the table.

I am not getting the idea how to keep track of this entities (namely: "refer a friend" and "customer") as to provide them both a discount on a purchase.

In which part of my program should I write the this conditional code and what could the code be? If anyone has any insight to this, please give some suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By what means you are referring, by mail or something else

Comment: referring by the referId

Comment: I mean to say when you refer someone you are referring it by a mail or from any other social media

Comment: okay that way....by email /sms

Comment: okay so you can send that referrer id along with link for the same and can get that value when user clicks on that link and forwards toward your index or register page, and save it into db

Comment: the id is already in the db, so do i just need to compare both the ids?

Comment: No when you bind your id with the link get that id from the redirected page ,match it and store that id within your db for that user as referfrom if you already have or add a field of like that

Comment: okay, thank you....this will solve my problem :) @NarendraSisodia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the Id along with the link that is to be redirected and get that id from redirected page, match the ID before submission within db and store it within db field as of referfrom or of your choice.